# How do I open a new File, while using my other File in Pygame?

Tags: python, file, pygame

So I made a main menu with buttons. An Start button and an Quit button. I already programmed the Quit button to quit pygame. Now I wan't to put the function into my Start button that does this:
Open another Python File where the Main Game Part is happening. I made a new Python File named "Testo.py".
Then I wen't to the code part where the Start button's uses are and wrote: open(file="Testo.py"). But nothing happens. I'll give you the code for both buttons but the main part is at the "greenButton"(or Start button). I hope you can understand what I mean.

```
run = True
greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 255, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button ((255, 0, 0), 280, 380, 250, 100, "Quit")
while run:
    redrawWindow()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
                open(file="Testo.py")
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

Edit: I asked a new question and now I understand how. Sorry, I apparently formulated this question wrong and this question was asked as I didn't know much pygame/python. Anyways, thank you for all the ones who answered on this question. I hope others that read this will get the answer they needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are more than a few ways. I'll list them in order of inverted
>   preference (*i.e.*, best first, worst last):
>
> 1. **Treat it like a module:** `import file`. This is good because it's secure, fast, and maintainable. Code gets reused as it's supposed
>      to be done. Most Python libraries run using multiple methods stretched
>      over lots of files. Highly recommended. Note that if your file is
>      called `file.py`, your `import` should *not* include the `.py`
>      extension at the end.
> 2. **The infamous (and unsafe) [exec](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#exec) command:** Insecure, hacky, usually the wrong answer. Avoid where possible.
>
>    - `execfile('file.py')` in Python 2
>    - `exec(open('file.py').read())` in Python 3
> 3. **Spawn a shell process:** `os.system('python file.py')`. Use when desperate.

From [apc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567779/apc)

Comment: if you treat it like a module then you have to put in the python folder itself

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file with `open` lets you read/write to that file as if it was open in a text editor. I would assume you want to execute the python code written in that file? In that case, you have to import it and call the function you want to execute. For example:

```py
import Testo
Testo.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
execfile('Testo.py')
```

but i suggest you import it and use run it

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how you mean it. Could you please write it (import and run it) how I should write it? I'm new

Comment: check out the reply by Luka Mesaric